# How to center text & images in a CompoundDrawable?

Tags: android

A CompoundDrawable is a TextView with an image and a text right? So if it's a combination of the two, how can you put the text in the center with respect to the image? Or how can you put the image in the center with respect to the text if the text is a bit smaller compared to the image? Or what if the image is smaller than the text? How could I cover these scenarios using `XML`?

Here is an example of a CompoundDrawable:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"
     android:text="@string/text" />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to your TextView.

Comment: it did sorry about that thank you.one more how can i put the text on the side of the image or vice versa?

Comment: @HakHak, use android:drawableLeft, android:drawableRight, etc to place the image elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/filterView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background_card"
    android:text="Offers"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/small_badge_dollar"
    android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/offers_color"`enter code here`
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Play around android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"

Answer (score 1):

```
cool stuff with android:drawablePadding="-20dp" android:paddingLeft="20dp"

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pre"
        style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bottom_tab"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/prev"
        android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
        android:onClick="navigateStaticPages"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/pre"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/login_textSize" />
```

Comment: one question is it a good practice to put negative value on padding?will it have draw back?

Comment: I'm using in my layout, I didn't see any drawback. depends  your requirement.

Comment: But if my textview is match parent(0dp) then?